# Injecting current git commit id into Java webapp

Tags: java, git, ant

We have a git repository which contains source for a few related Java WARs and JARs. It would be nice if the Java code could somehow:

```
System.err.println("I was built from git commit " + commitID);
```

(Obviously real code might be putting this into an HTTP header, logging it on startup, or whatever, that's not important right now)

We are using Ant to build (at least for production builds, it seems some programmers do their testing from inside Eclipse which I know even less about) binaries.

Is there a canonical way to get the commit id for the current git checkout into our Java at build time? If not, can people using Ant to build suggest how they'd do it and we'll see if a canonical solution emerges? I'm sure I can invent something myself entirely from whole cloth, but this seems like a re-usable building block, so I'd rather not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if there are any Ant task for git (I googled a bit without success), anyway Ant can update a properties file with Piotr's option (`git rev-parse HEAD`) and then in runtime use that properties to get the revision number. This is cleaner and *IDE friendly* than having Ant generating a .java file.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer for the question. I was really hoping to get more Ant-specific material, the Git side of the equation which got most feedback is the one I already had pretty good ideas for. But the suggestion to use a properties file seems like a good one.

Answer (score 14):

You can get the last commit SHA with

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

but it's generally a lot more useful to use

```
git describe
```

which will give you something that looks like this:

```
v0.7.0-185-g83e38c7
```

This works if you have tags - it will tell you how many commits from the last valid tag your current checkout is at plus a partial SHA for that commit, so you can use it to base a checkout off of later.  You can use this identifier just like a SHA in most circumstances, but it's much more human readable.

Comment: If you are wondering wht is that **'g'**: _"The hash suffix is "-g" + 7-char abbreviation for the tip commit of parent (which was 2414721b194453f058079d897d13c4e377f92dc6). The "g" prefix stands for "git" and is used to allow describing the version of a software depending on the SCM the software is managed with. This is useful in an environment where people may use different SCMs."_. Source: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe

Answer (score 7):

If it helps for someone else. I know yours is ANT

For **MAVEN** build, you could probably use ***git-commit-id-plugin*** in your **pom.xml** file

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>revision</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
            <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
            <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Please go through : 
1. http://www.baeldung.com/spring-git-information & 
2. https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin for more info.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an Ant task to get the buildnumber using JGit API (without git command line app), see [jgit-buildnumber-ant-task](https://github.com/alx3apps/jgit-buildnumber). Then you can store this buildnumber inside MANIFEST.MF file and get it from the classpath on runtime.

Answer (score 2):

`git rev-parse HEAD` will print what you probably want (e.g. id of `HEAD` commit).
You can make ant generate a simple Java class with this id as a static constant.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can use `ident` [gitattribute](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) with `$Id$` keyword (although it is not probably what you want; it is hash of file contents, and has nothing to do with current project version).

Second, you can do it the way Linux kernel and Git itself do it: in Makefile (in your case: in Ant file) there is rule which replaces some placeholder, usually '@@VERSION@@' (but in case of Perl it is '++VERSION++') by result of [GIT-VERSION-GEN](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=GIT-VERSION-GEN;hb=master), which in turn uses **"[git describe](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html)"**. But for that to be useful you have to tag your releases (using annotated / signed tags).

Comment: $Id$ attribute is the blob id, so I don't think that's what we want (a change elsewhere won't update the blob)