# Git keyword-expansion or alternative

Tags: git, hash, commit, keyword-expansion

Having read some postings here about this topic, I realize that there are quite some cons that speak against using keyword-substitution.  Nevertheless, I need a way to solve following problem and hope that somebody might have an idea on how to solve this with git (whether or not with keyword-substitution):

I have a main application for which I use git as VCS. Parts of this main application (a certain set of XML-Files) are being used by a utility for which I also use git (separate repo).

Now, the main app and the utility have different release cycles, and whenever I release a new version of the utility, I copy over the most current set of XML-Files from the main application.
Within the utility, this set of XML-Files is non-versioned content in git, so it's not even checked in to the repo.

As of now, whenever I look at different releases of this utility (which is managed by git and has tagged releases) I have no way of knowing which "version" (better: commit hash) the set of contained XML-Files is referring to.

So I was thinking: if I can have the latest commit SHA within those XML-Files (as a comment), I'd always know to which set of XML-Files a certain version of my utility refers to.
Is there anything wrong in this approach or is this the way to go? If yes, how do I get the latest commit-SHA into my XML-Files? (I read that $Id:$ won't take the commit-SHA, but some "blob"-SHA?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, based on your input, this is what i did:

1. Insert placeholders in my XML-Files: `<!-- @GIT_VERSION@ -->`
2. Have ant pick up git version information, note that this is Windows:
3. Have ant insert this info into my XML-Files while copying them over.

Code:

```
<target name="getGitDetails">
    <exec executable="cmd" outputproperty="git.revision">
         <arg value="/c" />
         <arg value="git.cmd --git-dir=<path-to-repo> describe --long --dirty --always" />
    </exec>
     <exec executable="cmd" outputproperty="git.currentBranchRef">
         <arg value="/c" />
         <arg value="git.cmd --git-dir=<path-to-repo> describe --all" />
     </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="build" depends="getGitDetails">
     <copy todir="<dest-dir>">  
         <filterset>
             <filter token="GIT_VERSION" value="${git.currentBranchRef} ${git.revision}" />
         </filterset>
     </copy>
 </target>
```

Thanks for your help!

See also:

[How to lookup the latest git commit hash from an ant build script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974106/how-to-lookup-the-latest-git-commit-hash-from-an-ant-build-script)

[Deriving application build version from `git describe` - how to get a relatively straightforward string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300746/deriving-application-build-version-from-git-describe-how-to-get-a-relatively)

Answer (score 5):

Two choices

**Using Submodules**

You can build main app as repo + submodule for XML-data. Because you can't use *part of git-repo* as submodule in another repo, *only full* repo (Git-boys, FIXME), you have re-create utility-repo as "supermodule" and split repo into two - utility + XML-data

Main repo becomes also "supermodule" and will 1) include main app and 2) XML-data for app

Because Git maintain strict relation between changesets in main repo and submodule for all and any base changeset-id (Git-boys, FIXME), you can only know hash of main app and get related to this changeset snapshot of XML-data

**Smudge-clean filters**

While maintaining repos as totally independent, you can add tracking data into XML-files. Proper way to add any arbitrary keyword to Git-controlled data is [Smudge-clean filters](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion) (see "Keyword Expansion" section and example for $Date$ keyword expansion)

Comment: I found a solution, see below. But i will have a look at Smudge-clean filters, thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 2):

If that XML file is not tracked by Git, then there is nothing wrong with this. I think it is a pretty good idea to have the hash a build is based on somewhere visible, so you always now when something comes up, what version of the source code this is based on.

Just for the completeness, it is not possible to have the hash value within a file that is tracked. This is because the hash is made based on all the information Git has. If it would insert the value into some tracked file, then that file would be changed, and either you would need to do another commit, or the previous commit would have to be changed – which would cause a different hash value.

As your file is not tracked, changes to it will not change the hash value, so the above is not an issue. There are multiple ways of getting the current SHA1 hash, the simplest is probably simply by looking into `.git/refs/heads/master`. That file is the pointer for the `master` branch, and contains the hash of the HEAD commit in that branch. Of course you can change `/master` to any other branch if you like.

Comment: Hm, and how would i get this hash-value into my XML-Files automatically? I certainly do not want to edit it manually everytime :) So it should be inserted whenever i checkout the XML-Files, which i then copy over to the utility.

Comment: Note: Within the main-application the XML-Files are versioned, just not within the utility.

Comment: I would put it into the build/release step. I assume you have some more or less automated process that helps you releasing. At that point you could probably run a script that extracts the hash value and inserts it into the created XML file.

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution is to extend main application's build process so one of results would be packaged XML files. This packaged version would contain added information about main application's version. Such package would be convenient to bundle with external utilities etc.

During build you can obtain version information directly from git with either `git describe` or `git rev-parse HEAD` (see [Injecting current git commit id into Java webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020354/injecting-current-git-commit-id-into-java-webapp))

Comment: Concerning `git describe`: I cannot get it to print my branch name as well - I don't only want to include <tag>-<nr of commits>-<commit hash> but also the currently checked out branch. Do you know how to achieve this? `--all` is printing the branch ref, but omitting the version info..

Comment: @quayalar a) You can use both commands and merge results, but... b) Remember that in git branches are neither persistent nor universal. Today branch name may mean something, tomorrow the branch doesn't exist any more. Also branches are local to repository, which makes them meaningless in distributed system. OTOH commit hashes and tags are the exact opposite; I'd stick to them.

Comment: ad a) This is what i did :)
ad b) Yes i realize that, but this is information that is essentially just for myself - i just want to know from which branch this checkout came, to immediately see if i built my utility from the wrong set of XML-Files (they should just come from the master or develop branch).