# How to retrieve the git commit hash (or description) of a directory with Java

Tags: java, git

I would like a method that retrieves the git commit description (or commit hash --I'm not picky!) for a specified codebase.  Something along the lines of:

```
public static retrieveGitDescription(File repositoryDirectory) {
    // magic!
}
```

The closest thing I could fine is this SO post about [Injecting current git commit id into Java webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020354/injecting-current-git-commit-id-into-java-webapp), however I want to fetch the information at runtime.

Comment: Use shell commands or http://eclipse.org/jgit/ or https://github.com/kevinsawicki/gitective, many post on SO about JGit

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Embedding-Git-in-your-Applications-JGit